# Filter all columns that contain a number above/below a threshold using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset contains numerical values between -1 to 1.

I want to filter it so it **returns only the columns where the lowest value exceeds -0.3.**

as a dummy dataset:

[image: So I'd want to return only columns g1 and g5 as they have at least one value below -0.3 threshold.]

So I'd want to return only columns g1 and g5 as they have at least one value below -0.3 threshold.

The real dataset is much larger than this and I would like to know how to do this in **dplyr**.

If there are any better packages or tools please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various way to do this :

In base R,

using `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(x < -0.3), df)
```

with `apply`

```
df[apply(df < -0.3, 2, any)]
#Similar with sapply
#df[sapply(df, function(x) any(x < -0.3))]
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(~any(. < -0.3))

#     g1    g5
#1 -0.05  0.90
#2  0.00  0.54
#3  0.10 -0.44
#4  0.00  0.30
#5  0.15  0.07
#6 -0.56  0.06
#7 -0.70  0.22
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(g1 = c(-0.05, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.15, -0.56, -0.7), 
                 g2 = c(0, 0.03, -0.04, 0.015, -0.05, -0.06, -0.08), 
                 g3 = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.12, 0.11, -0.01, -0.02, 0.02), 
                 g4 = c(0.6, 0.37, 0.28, 0.205, 0.03, 0.02, 0.12), 
                 g5 = c(0.9, 0.54, -0.44, 0.3, 0.07, 0.06, 0.22))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` we can use `colSums` on a logical matrix

```
df[colSums(df <  -0.3) > 0]
```

Or with `sapply`

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) any(x < -0.3))]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(g1 = c(-0.05, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.15, -0.56, -0.7), 
                 g2 = c(0, 0.03, -0.04, 0.015, -0.05, -0.06, -0.08), 
                 g3 = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.12, 0.11, -0.01, -0.02, 0.02), 
                 g4 = c(0.6, 0.37, 0.28, 0.205, 0.03, 0.02, 0.12), 
                 g5 = c(0.9, 0.54, -0.44, 0.3, 0.07, 0.06, 0.22))
```